# How can I get the page number and position for a specific pdf form field and insert a table in it's place in iText7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I wanted to insert a Table in the position of the form field. How do I get the position and page number of the form field? How do I insert the table in that location?

```
//Retrieves AcroForm from the document.
//If there is no AcroForm in the document Catalog and createIfNotExist
//flag is true then the AcroForm dictionary will be created and added to the document.
PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
//Gets the form fields as a Map.
Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = acroForm.getFormFields();
//Create Table
Table table = new Table(new float[]{1,1});
table.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
table.setWidthPercent(95);  
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.add(new Paragraph("Name"));
//cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.add(new Paragraph("Address"));
//cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);
...
...
doc.add(table);
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Field by itself does not have any position or page number. However, its widget annotations do.

To access those, you can use `field.getWidgets()`. You then can use `annotation.getPage()` and `annotation.getRectangle()` to get information about the annotation's position.

To layout an single element at some specific position, one of the best choices is using `Canvas` layout object. Annotation can then be removed with `page.removeAnnotation(annotation);`.

Overall, this compiles into following solution:

```
String fieldName = "Text1";
PdfFormField field = form.getField(fieldName);

for (PdfAnnotation annotation : field.getWidgets()) {
    PdfPage page = annotation.getPage();
    Rectangle rectangle = annotation.getRectangle().toRectangle();

    Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPointArray(new float[] {-1, -1}));
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    cell.add(new Paragraph("Name"));
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new Cell();
    cell.add(new Paragraph("Address"));
    table.addCell(cell);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(new PdfCanvas(page), pdfDocument, rectangle);
    canvas.add(table);
    canvas.close();

    page.removeAnnotation(annotation);
}
```

Of course, you will have to take full responsibility for creating a table of proper size so that it fits into the area you want. You can use smaller font sizes etc.

Comment: Thank You. @AlexeySubach